# Javascript files can't be found and loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I am following a tutorial, which uses the MEAN stack. I got to the point where I'm supposed to start using Node. Everything is installed and I've put the angular and bootstrap scripts in the respective folder. The problem is that none of these files are found when I try to run the application in localhost:3000.

The errors I'm getting:

[image: The errors I'm getting]

The directory structure of my project:

[image: The directory structure of my project]

This is the code I've got so far :

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app = "flapperNews">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/stylesheets/bootstrap.css">

<style>
    .glyphicon-thumbs-up {
        cursor : pointer;
    }
</style>



<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

<div class = "row">

    <div class = "col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"> 

        <ui-view></ui-view>

     </div>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id = "/home.html">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class = "page-header">
                 <h1>Flapper News</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ng-click="upvote(post)"></span>
            {{post.upvotes}}
        <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
            <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
                {{post.title}}
            </a>
            <span ng-hide="post.link">
                {{post.title}}
            </span>
        </span>

        <span>
            <a href="#/posts/{{$index}}">Comments</a>
        </span>

    </div>

    <form ng-submit="addPost()" style="margin-top:30px;">
        <h3>Add a new post</h3>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" ng-model="newPost.title"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Link" ng-model="newPost.link"></input>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>

    </form>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">
    <div class = "page-header">
        <h3> 
            <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">{{post.title}}</a>
            <span ng-hide = "post.link">{{post.title}}</span>
        </h3>
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat = "comment in post.comments | orderBy : '-upvotes'">
        <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ng-click = "upvote(comment)">
            {{comment.upvotes}} - by {{comment.author}}
        </span>
        <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
            {{comment.body}}
        </span>

    </div>

    <form ng-submit = addComment() style = "margin-top:30px;">
        <h3>Add a new comment</h3>


        <div class = "form-group">
            <input type="text" class = "form-control" ng-model = "body" placeholder="Comment">
            <button type="submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Post</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</script>

</body>

<script src = "../public/javascripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src = "../public/javascripts/mean.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="../public/javascripts/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<script src="../public/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

**mean.js**

```
var app = angular.module("flapperNews",['ui.router','ui.bootstrap']);

// Injecting the posts service into the controller so
// we can access its data
app.controller ("mainCtrl",function ($scope,posts) {
    // Binding the scope.posts variable in our controller 
    // to the posts array in our service
    $scope.posts = posts.posts;

    $scope.addPost = function () {
        if ($scope.newPost.title === "" || !$scope.newPost.title) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            $scope.posts.push({title : $scope.newPost.title ,link : $scope.newPost.link,upvotes : "0",
  comments: [
    {author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 0},
    {author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!', upvotes: 0}
  ]
        });
            $scope.newPost.title = "";
            $scope.newPost.link = "";
        }


    }

    $scope.upvote = function (post) {
        post.upvotes ++ ;
    }

});

app.controller("postsCtrl",function ($scope,$stateParams,posts) {

    $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];

    $scope.addComment  = function () {
        if ($scope.body === "") {
            return;
        }
        else {
                $scope.post.comments.push({
                body : $scope.body,
                author : "user",
                upvotes : 0
            });
        $scope.body = "";
        }
    }

});

// We're creating an object with an array property called posts
app.factory("posts",[function () {
    var o = {
            posts : []
        };
    return o;
}])

app.config (["$stateProvider","$urlRouterProvider",function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvier) {
// Configuring a home state
    $stateProvider
        .state("home",{
            url: "/home",
            templateUrl : "/home.html",
            controller : "mainCtrl"
        })
        .state("posts",{
            // id is a route parameter
            url : "/posts/{id}",
            templateUrl : "/posts.html",
            controller : "postsCtrl"
        });

    $urlRouterProvier.otherwise("home");
}]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You needn't reference your assets with the `public`folder in your path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/stylesheets/bootstrap.css">
```

Assuming you have set your `public` folder in your `express`server as below (your `app.js` in this case), you should see a line similar to below

```
 app.use(express.static('public'));
```

This is where the default location for public assets i.e your css etc are defined.Rather just do

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/bootstrap.css">
```

As `express` will navigate to the defined public folder by default.

Comment: Just edited the code and everything is working properly. Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Is `app.js` your server file? If so, is it in your `public` folder? Apologies, but it's hard to tell from the picture.

If that's the case, you don't need to include `public` in your filepaths.

Also, are you serving up a static folder? (using `app.use(express.static('public')`); It's good practice to do so -- what this does is serve only the `public` folder - all paths in the html will be relative to this folder, as if it was the directory. Doing this means you could also take the `public` out of your filepaths. It's good practice, as I said, because generally you want to reveal as little of your server structure as possible - serving only one static folder like this helps.

Comment: From what I've read **app.js** is the file used for importing modules,configuring routes,etc. Sorry, if I'm not being helpful, I'm really new to all this. 
The file is located outside the "public" folder. It's inside the main folder "flapper-news".

Comment: is app.js where Express is instantiated? I.E, is it the starting script, i.ei.e is it the script package.json points to to start the server?

Comment: Yes,that's the one. It's fixed now, thank you for your help though.

Comment: add `app.use(express.static('public'));` to app.js after Express gets instantiated, change the filepaths to cut out `public` like so:

   `<link href="stylesheets/bootstrap.css"></link>`

Answer (score 0):

If you using the express routes you need to set static path in `app.js`, something like:

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

And in index.ejs:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/stylesheets/bootstrap.css"
```